# stuck in a andriod zoom in page in windiows

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

[zoomed in :/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5SR0.png)

I was changing the looks of my android studio settings >apprentice >size.
Mistakenly from 15 to 115 and it reacted so fast that it glitched and kicked me out the setting menu I couldn't to anything.
-I tried unistalling it
-Try opening ALT +V then go to appearance and zoom out couldn't do that
-Am so stuck and confuse

it may be simple but am new to this sorry .

I was changing the looks of my android studio settings >apprentice >size.